# Getting to a SharePoint Online Picture Library with just the URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I am trying to retrieve a specific item from a SharePoint, however I am not able to get to it.   The Url which I am getting to is

`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/ContentCenter/Lists/ProposalContent`,

I am able to get to it using a string builder to build the Url for example

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(library))
            {
                pth += "/lists/" + library;
            }
```

How ever a picture library the url is

`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/ContentCenter/Graphics`

I am having trouble building the url to that picture library.  I actually have a static Url to the picture, but I am not get the image in order for me to convert it to base 64

**My desired result:**

Being able to get to my picture lib in order to retrieve the specific item and then turn it to base 64,  I have the relative url to that item in the pic lib but I can't get to it.

**appendix**

I am using SharePoint online CSOM

**Non Working Code**

```
 try
                    {

                    System.Uri test = new System.Uri("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/ContentCenter/Graphics/map-al.jpg"); << this is the direct URL to the image in the pic lib

                            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(test.AbsolutePath);


                            ClientResult<Stream> stream = file.OpenBinaryStream();

                            var testViewStreamValue = stream.Value;

                            context.Load(file);
                            context.ExecuteQuery();



                            if (stream != null)   << is not returning the proper base 64
                            {
                                using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 64];
                                    int nread = 0;

                                    while ((nread = stream.Value.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                                    {
                                        memory.Write(buffer, 0, nread);
                                    }
                                    memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);


                                    string testbase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
                                    var testthisStop = 0;


                            }
```

Comment: You should share your CSOM code. The portion you provided only shows building a relative path for a list, which you've stated is not what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just posted the code which I am using, I am getting base 64 from but when validating the base 64  it is invalid.  My goal is to get the image from the static url and convert it to base 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felt my way around this issue and found out that retrieving what I wanted was a bit similar to getting items from a list.  This is very simple and I consider it to be a cookie cutter template.

Acquiring Client Context came from an other function and will not be displayed.

```
 Uri UrltoPicLib = new System.Uri("https://"yourTenant".com/sites/ContentCenter/Graphics");

 var baseUrl = UrltoPicLib .GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
 var fileServerRelativeUrl = UrltoPicLib .ToString().Replace(baseUrl, string.Empty);


   try
   {
            var files = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(fileServerRelativeUrl).Files;
            context.Load(files);
            context.ExecuteQuery();


            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in files)
            {
                ClientResult<System.IO.Stream> data = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                context.Load(file);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                using (System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        data.Value.CopyTo(mStream);
                        byte [] imageArray = mStream.ToArray();
                        string b64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);


                    }
                }
            }
        }
catch (Exception exp)
{

}
```

}

Comment: If this worked for you, you should mark it as the solution.

Comment: I was trying to but it says I have to wait 2 days.  I will be back to mark it as answered in two days\